# Webpack LESS loader, happens after page render

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

I'm using `webpack`, with `less-loader` and this configuration:

```
  {
    test: /\.less$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: "style!raw!less"
  },
```

Everything works fine, except that CSS rules are loaded **after the page is rendered**, creating a 1-second flicker of unstyled content.

How can load CSS **before** my scripts (I'm using React) render the page?

Answer (score 2):

With [ExtractTextPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin) you can extract styles from js bundle into separate css file, which can be added to `<head>` tag in usual way:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```